# Get Height of a view inside UITabelViewCell dynamically changed

Tags: ios, uitableview

I made a custom UIView doing some animation on it.
I need to calculate it's frame size because it differs in iPhone 6, 6 plus and iPhone 5.

I am using

```
self.frame, self.layer.presentationlayer.frame
```

but all of them gives wrong frame, I need the frame of the view after it appears inside the Cell.
in  cellForRowAtIndexPath i call this function

```
[cell.answer1 showStatistics:percent];
```

in the method first i made

```
 CGRect Frame= self.frame;
dempedLayer=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:Frame];
[dempedLayer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[dempedLayer setAlpha:0.35];
[self addSubview:dempedLayer];
```

then i make some animation using CAShapeLayer and CABasicAnimation

```
CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"]
```

Comment: Can you post a piece of code where you call those methods, so we can see how your views look like

Comment: @SteBra i put the code

Comment: Make a class method of UITableViewCell(If cell is custom) and then in your view controller's heightForRowAtIndexPath, call that method to get cell height on the basis of its data.

Answer (score -1):

if you are trying to do animation here is how can achieve it:-

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations^{

CGRect viewFrame = self.yourView.frame;

viewFrame.size.height += 100; 

self.yourView.frame = viewFrame;

}];
```

if this is not what you are looking for, may be you should check the autoresizing parameters you are setting in the IB/Storyboard.

Comment: actually i use CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation=[CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"]